# Unicode issue python

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to decode an email information with accents, but I am getting an error, what am I doing wrong? Just added the full traceback.

```
import gmail
import unicodedata

g = gmail.login('mail@gmail.com', 'myPass')

messagesPaypal = g.inbox().mail(unread=True, sender="member@paypal.com")

messagesPaypal[0].fetch()
data = messagesPaypal[0].body[500:900]

#print data

print data.decode('unicode-escape')


#ERROR:

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\admin> python "D:\\automate\\gmailExtract.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\\automate\\gmailExtract.py", line 130, in <module>
    print data.decode('unicode-escape')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\x82' in position 106: character maps to <undefined>
PS C:\Users\admin>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: For unicode problems please always tag your python version, since unicode is way different in python 2 and 3.

Comment: @dhke definitely Py2 here, but tagging it is always best.

Comment: What are you attempting to do with `.decode('unicode-escape')`? It seems unlikely PayPal will be sending you mail with Python Unicode string literals in the body.

Comment: @JeromeJ You should be able to suggest the re-tag via *edit*. Gives score when approved :-). I won't to it since I wasn't sure enough.

Comment: just edited the question with the error. python 2.7

Comment: the message comes with many accents, and I get strange characters, I want to read the message with the correct characters just like in the gmail inbox.

Comment: Be sure that `data` is `str` type, and `unicode-escape` is an acceptable encoding.

Comment: Could you copy/paste your error in your post? Or show us an sample of wrong output. (Btw, Python3 is better with handling unicode issues overall. I personally won't mess with Py2 anymore, so this is as far as I can help you currently)

Comment: just added the error i am getting

Comment: `charmap`?? Could you give us the full traceback? Is it raised on the `data.decode` line?

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec cant encode character u'\x82' in position 106: character maps to <undefined>

Its the last line giving the error.

Comment: What about the full traceback? Not only the last line. Please include it in your post. Also, don't forget to tag my name when replying to me (with "@JeromeJ") so I get notification that you replied to me.

Comment: @JeromeJ Just added the full traceback, thank you.

Comment: `data.decode('unicode-escape')` converts a binary string to unicode, when using `print` on this python2 tries encode this according to the output encoding, which is what fails. A strong hint that the original data is _not_ `unicode-escape`-encoded.

Comment: @mata Propose it as an answer? Indeed, the hint that Py2 is doing stuff in your back (which Py3 wouldn't) is that even though you call a `decode` method, you can see that the error has been raised with a `encode`, so basically your stuff is already decoded, so Py2 tries to encode it for you before decoding it as you requested. This behavior, supposed to help, often turns out to not help.